# Possible to use Spark Pandas UDF in pure Spark SQL?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This works:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

@pandas_udf(returnType="long")
def add_one(v: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return v.add(1)

spark.udf.register("add_one", add_one)

spark.sql("select add_one(1)").show()
```

However, I'm wondering if/how I can make the following work:

```
$ spark-sql -e 'select add_one(1)'
```

Comment: is it possible to use Java/Scala instead of Python?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use PySpark UDFs, only Java/Scala UDFs would work. The Spark SQL CLI does not start the infrastructure required for PySpark (for example the Py4J component).

Comment: @werner can you point me to an example of creating a UDF in Java? as simple as possible please. thanks

Comment: Create a SparkListener that adds the UDF to the SparkSession: `import org.apache.spark.scheduler.*; import org.apache.spark.sql.*; import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*; import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
public class SL extends SparkListener { @Override         public void onApplicationStart(SparkListenerApplicationStart as) {      SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();     spark.udf().register("add_one", (UDF1<Integer, Integer>)i -> i+1, DataTypes.IntegerType);   } }`.

Comment: Then compile the class, put the class file into a jar and add it it the command line: `spark-sql --jars SL.jar --conf spark.extraListeners=SL -e 'select add_one(1)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that would be very nice if one could use that.

I'm afraid that this is currently not possible. Funny is that nobody actually mentions it.

The information is actually *"hidden"* in the apache spark documentation in a small note:

> Note that the Spark SQL CLI cannot talk to the Thrift JDBC server.

As you probably understand the implications that means you can't call `UDFs` from the CLI `spark-sql`.  Here is the [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-spark-sql-cli) to the documentation.

One can double check the `bin/spark-sql` [source code at github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-sql) what is actually done:

```
if [ -z "${SPARK_HOME}" ]; then
  source "$(dirname "$0")"/find-spark-home
fi

export _SPARK_CMD_USAGE="Usage: ./bin/spark-sql [options] [cli option]"
exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver "$@"
```

That again confirms, as it submits it to `thriftserver`, that you can't use the `UDF` at `spark-sql` CLI.

Comment: how would you go about hacking things so you could accomplish it? could I write a wrapper to spark-submit that uses pyspark in the background but appears to load a sql file? thanks

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan good question. Well you could try it but to hack it that way; I'm not sure if that will work for you. The only way is to try it out. I think the only proper way is to create a PR on `...thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver` to support `UDF`.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas UDFs are vectorized UDFs meant to avoid row by row iterations inside PySpark. Once these UDFs are registered, they behave like PySpark Function APIs. They will reside and run inside Python worker.

As @tukan mentioned, Spark SQL CLI cannot talk to JDBC server. So, Spark doesn't natively support this.

However, you can make a custom RPC call to invoke it directly but that's not as easy or same as what you want to do in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use Python UDF in the way you want at this moment. But the option is available for Scala/Java UDF, so if you're open to using Scala/Java, this is one way to do it. Note: I'm implementing HiveUDF as [Spark supports HiveUDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-hive.html).

The first thing you need to do is create a Java project with the following sample structure:

```
root
| - pom.xml
| - src/main/com/test/udf/SimpleConcatUDF.java
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.udf</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-concat-udf</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <hive.version>3.1.2</hive.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>hortonworks</id>
      <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>${hive.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9</version>
          <configuration>
            <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.test.udf.SimpleConcatUDF</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

**SimpleConcatUDF.java**

```java
package com.test.udf;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class SimpleConcatUDF extends UDF {

  public String evaluate(final Text text) {
    return text.toString() + "_from_udf";
  }

}
```

The next thing you'd want to do is compile and package it. I'm using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) so the standard command is:

```sh
cd <project-root-path>/
mvn clean install
# output jar file is located at <project-root-path>/target/simple-concat-udf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Finally, you'd need to register it using [`create function`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html#content). This just needs to be done **once** if you register the function as permanent. Otherwise, you can register it as temporary.

```
spark-sql> create function simple_concat AS 'com.test.udf.SimpleConcatUDF' using jar '<project-root-path>/target/simple-concat-udf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar';
spark-sql> show user functions;
default.simple_concat
Time taken: 1.868 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
spark-sql> select simple_concat('a');
a_from_udf
Time taken: 0.079 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
```

**NOTE**: If you have HDFS in your system, you'd want to copy the jar file to HDFS and create function using that HDFS path instead of local path like above.

Comment: do you know how do to this without extending Hive UDF? (via Spark UDF)